# Customized radio button in qml

Tags: qml

I want a window with 3 push button but this push buttons should work like radio button!
so this is my code:

```
Rectangle {
    id: sideButton
    color:  sideButtonMouseArea.containsMouse ? '#DDDDDD' : '#F4F4F4'
    property string text: 'Button'
    MouseArea {
        id: sideButtonMouseArea
        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled: true
        onClicked: {
            parent.color = '#4872E8'
            sideButtonLabel.color = '#E2EBFC'
        }
    }

    Text {
        id: sideButtonLabel
        text: sideButton.text
        font.pixelSize: 20
        font.family: 'Tahoma'
        anchors.centerIn: sideButton
        color: '#787878'
    }
}
```

I use this rectangle instead button but it has a proble when click on other button for 2end time 
how could i fix it?

Comment: Maybe you could be more specific about your problem... and maybe you should take a look at this: http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#classic

Comment: "I use this rectangle instead button" --- so, button is an option, however, button is not a part of qtquick core. What external library do you use? `qt-components` for symbian/meego or something from Ubuntu phone? Please also, check, maybe there is a standard component for radio button?

Answer (score 5):

This code works for me:

**MyRadioGroup.qml**

```
import QtQuick 1.0

QtObject {
    property Item selected : null
}
```

**MyRadioButton.qml**

```
import QtQuick 1.0

Rectangle {
    id: sideButton
    property string text: 'Button'
    property MyRadioGroup radioGroup

    color:  radioGroup.selected === sideButton ? '#E2EBFC' :
            (sideButtonMouseArea.containsMouse ? '#DDDDDD' : '#F4F4F4')
    MouseArea {
        id: sideButtonMouseArea
        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled: true
        onClicked: sideButton.radioGroup.selected = sideButton
    }

    Text {
        id: sideButtonLabel
        text: sideButton.text
        font.pixelSize: 20
        font.family: 'Tahoma'
        anchors.centerIn: sideButton
        color: radioGroup.selected === sideButton ? '#E2EBFC' : '#787878'
    }
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 1.0

Rectangle {
    height: 600
    width: 600

    MyRadioGroup {
        id: radioGroup1
    }

    Column {
        anchors.fill: parent

        MyRadioButton {
            anchors { left: parent.left; right: parent.right }
            text: "Button 1"
            radioGroup: radioGroup1
            height: 100
        }

        MyRadioButton {
            anchors { left: parent.left; right: parent.right }
            text: "Button 2"
            radioGroup: radioGroup1
            height: 100
        }

        MyRadioButton {
            anchors { left: parent.left; right: parent.right }
            text: "Button 3"
            radioGroup: radioGroup1
            height: 100
        }

        MyRadioButton {
            anchors { left: parent.left; right: parent.right }
            text: "Button 4"
            radioGroup: radioGroup1
            height: 100
        }
    }   
}
```

What it does: I've created container `MyRadioGroup` to hold currently selected item. Then, I declaratively bind its `selected` property with `color` property of my `MyRadioButton`-s, so it will update on every `selected` change.

---

Having that said, please check, that you component provider doesn't already contain some stuff like this --- maybe you are reinventing the wheel.